# How to use a subclassed cell from the IB without reusing it again?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I've created a cell with 2 `UIButton`s in the IB and subclassed it. How can I use it without reusing it over again? (for a small fixed table)
I tried doing something like:
`RaffleResultCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];`
but that won't show my cell in the `UITableView`, just a blank one.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        //Where we configure the cell in each row
        id currentRaffle = [_winnings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        RaffleResultCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"raffleResCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[RaffleResultCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"raffleResCell"];
        }
return cell;
}
```

Comment: `@"nil"` and not `nil`?

Comment: if you dont mind my asking, what makes you want to avoid reusability? this desire usually shows a problem with the design of your app.

Comment: It's a for a fixed small table. But basically I'm just curious for the answer because I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not a good practice to avoid Reusability,I will say dont do it**

Reusability is done in this line

```
RaffleResultCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"raffleResCell"];
```

Remove that line and just call alloc method everytime without the check loop

Like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       id currentRaffle = [_winnings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell = [[RaffleResultCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"raffleResCell"];
       return cell;
}
```

Comment: `RaffleResultCell *cell = [[RaffleResultCell alloc]init];` Like this? I'm still getting a blank cell.

Comment: You haven't configured cell in your example. this `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    RaffleResultCell *cell = [[RaffleResultCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"raffleResCell"];   
    return cell;
}` still gives me a blank cell.

Comment: That is the problem of your subclass of cell it is not properly set up

Answer (score 0):

You told you set up the UITableViewCell in IB then you need to get Nib file and then use that file as

```
// Get nib file from mainBundle
NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RaffleResultCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            RaffleResultCell *cell = (RaffleResultCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
```

now setup any text for your button and return cell